# Cannot play 1080p content on Kodi using Nvidia Ion & proprietary diver 340.98, Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: nvidia, display, 16.10, xbmc, kodi

I have everything working perfectly all content plays at lower resolutions but I just get audio with a blank screen at 1080p.
Any advice would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the same codec or another one for 1080p? Have you checked (for example with htop in a terminal window) how much the CPU is working)? Are you using something like VDPAU to more work from the CPU to the GPU - and in that case, are you sure that it works with the encoding of the 1080p video?

Comment: What is the graphics adapter?

Comment: Installed and checked with htop and all seems to be as it should but I am a noob and don't how to check if VDPAU is working or not. sudodus

Comment: @Pilot6 He's using a nVidia ION GPU, which supports 1080p playback.

Comment: @Pilot6 got any tips?